# How to run a function that a on form submit ajax with automatic click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit a form with just automatic click button.

so I have a timer which is if the timer is already 0, it should submit the form automatically.

here is the code that I have.

```
function tick() {
    var timeDisplay = document.getElementById('question_timer');
    var isTimeLimit = true;
    var min = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 60);
    var sec = secondsRemaining - (min * 60);

    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
    }

    var message = min.toString() + ':' + sec;
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = message;

    //stop if down to zero
    if (secondsRemaining === 0 && isTimeLimit == true) {
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        displayQuestion();
    } else {
        //boolean is false
        if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
            submitAnswer();
            clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        }

    }

    secondsRemaining--;
}

function startCountdown() {

    clearInterval(intervalHandle);

    secondsRemaining = 5;

    intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}

function submitAnswer() {
    $('#form_question_scenario').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: url,
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

How can I run the submitAnswer function if the timer is already 0. any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need submit event at all, just call the function like you did when 0 sec is left, get id of form and create new form data, and do Ajax request...

```
function submitAnswer() {
let myForm = document.getElementById('form_question_scenario');
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: url,
            data: new FormData(myForm),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
            }
        });

}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

Form data is populated without submit event just by calling the function:

```js
function submitAnswer() {
  let myForm = document.getElementById('form_question_scenario');

  let data = new FormData(myForm)
  formObj = {};
  for (var pair of data.entries()) {
    formObj[pair[0]] = pair[1]
  }
  console.log(formObj)

}

submitAnswer()
```

```html
<form id="form_question_scenario">
  <input type="text" value="test" name="test">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi sir this solves my problem. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 2):

The `submitAnswer()` function just attaches the event handler, it doesn't actually submit the form.

To achieve what you require attach the `submit` event handler when the page loads, then when you want to submit the form trigger that event on it. Try this:

```js
// attach submit event handler when the page loads
$('#form_question_scenario').on('submit', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    // ajax settings here...
  });
});

function tick() {
  var timeDisplay = document.getElementById('question_timer');
  var isTimeLimit = true;
  var min = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 60);
  var sec = ('00' + (secondsRemaining - (min * 60))).slice(-2); // note tidied the logic here
  var message = min.toString() + ':' + sec;
  timeDisplay.innerHTML = message;

  // stop if down to zero
  if (secondsRemaining === 0 && isTimeLimit == true) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    displayQuestion();
  } else {
    if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
      $('#form_question_scenario').trigger('submit'); // submit the form here
      clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    }
  }

  secondsRemaining--;
}

function startCountdown() {
  clearInterval(intervalHandle);
  secondsRemaining = 5;
  intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
```